# In Xamarin.Forms for WPF, is there an equivalent to the symbols __IOS__ and __ANDROID__

Tags: wpf, xamarin, xamarin.forms

This would be convenient for some cases...  I can't find it.

I'd like to use it especially for those cases when I would use Xamarin.Essentials, which is not available yet for WPF.

Comment: Assuming you are using a shared project for your cross-platform code, so just add your own compiler symbol to your WPF application project. (that is all the default Xamarin iOS/android ones are, look at the compiler symbols for those projects)

Comment: So, it sounds like there is not one.  Makes sense, now that I think of it.  But, I'm embarrassed to say, I'm not sure how/where to add it in VS2017.   Oh, wait, on Project properties Build page, Conditional compilation symbols.  I'll give it a try.